# Sort two arrays of different values maintaining original pairing

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two js arrays, one contains strings, the other color codes, something like:

```
strings = ['one', 'twooo', 'tres', 'four'];
colors = ['000000', 'ffffff', 'cccccc', '333333'];
```

I need to sort the first array by the length of the values, longer first. I know I can do something like:

```
strings.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
});
```

But this way I am losing the color assined to each string. How can I sort both arrays keeping the keys pairing?

Comment: Why not just a single array of Objects

Comment: Sometimes you can't just recode hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: There's always the trick of creating a third array from 1 to the length of the other two arrays and sorting that. Then you can rearrange the other two arrays. Or you can write your own sort code and do two swaps instead of one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blatantly copied from [Sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and adapted.

It just uses the same sort order for the other array.

```js
// the array to be sorted
var strings = ['one', 'twooo', 'tres', 'four'],
    colors = ['000000', 'ffffff', 'cccccc', '333333'];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = strings.map(function (el, i) {
    return { index: i, value: el.length };
})

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
});

// container for the resulting order
var resultStrings = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return strings[el.index];
});
var resultColors = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return colors[el.index];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(resultStrings, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(resultColors, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: `toLowerCase` call is redundant since strings are not actually compared during `sort`

Comment: only issue map is not supported with ie-8.

Comment: @zakaiter, [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) is helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
var strings = [{name:'one',color:'000000'}, {name:'tres', color:'cccccc'}, {name:'four',color:'333333'}, {name: 'twooo', color:'ffffff'}];

var sorted= strings.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.name.length > b.name.length;  //sort length of name by ascending order  
});

console.log(sorted)
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sorted, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
strings = ['one', 'twooo', 'tres', 'four'];
colors = ['000000', 'ffffff', 'cccccc', '333333'];

var a = [];//temporary array, will store objects representing each key of both arrays
strings.forEach(function(k){
    a.push({s:k,c:colors[strings.indexOf(k)]});
});

a.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.s.length - a.s.length;
});

strings = [];
colors = [];

a.forEach(function(v){
    strings.push(v.s);
    colors.push(v.c);
});

console.log(strings);
console.log(colors);
```

Output:

```
["twooo", "tres", "four", "one"]
["ffffff", "cccccc", "333333", "000000"]
```

Comment: I like this code but one problem I found is repeated values in arr1 will be assigned the same color even when in the original arrays they were different.